# What does this JS Expression mean?

Tags: javascript

What does this JS expression mean? What are we returning?

`return dihy(year) in {353:1, 383:1};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `return` statement that causes the containing function to return a Boolean value.

1. It calls the function `dihy()` with the value of the variable `year` as its argument.
2. It checks whether the return value is either `353` or `383` (the names of the properties that exist *in* the object literal). It does not matter what value the property has; it just needs to exist within the object. (That is, `1` is just an arbitrary value.)
3. If so, the function returns `true`, otherwise `false`.

JavaScript programmers sometimes use this approach because it is shorter than checking against each value individually, and it is easy to programmatically add new values to check against:

```
var foo = {353: 1, 383: 1};

function bar(year) {
    return year in foo;
}

alert(bar(1955)); // false
foo[1955] = 1;
alert(bar(1955)); // true
```

You may want to look at the [MDC documentation for the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in).

Answer (score 2):

It will be `true` if the call to the function `dihy` with the argument `year` is a key in the object `{353:1, 383:1}` and `false` otherwise.

It could be rewritten like this for example:

```
var result = dihy(year);
return result == 353 || result == 383;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expression:

```
dihy(year) in {353:1, 383:1}
```

The `dihy(year)` function call presumably returns a Number value. If that value is either `353` or  `383`, the expression will evaluate to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

Note that your code is not an expression, but a statement, the `return` statement:

```
return expression;
```

So, the `return` statement will either return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Returns true or false, depending is the result that `dihy()` returns 353 or 383 (true for those two, anything else is false).

And it means exactly that... is the result of this function contained in this data collection...

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use an object here, i.e. `{353: 1, 383: 1}`. In fact, the values of 1 are confusing and can make the uninitiated think that the value of 1 is being returned when it is not and is purely arbitrary.

The following is equivalent:

```
dihy(year) in [353, 383]
```

Comment: That won't work. The array object has two keys: "0" which has the value 355, and "1" which has the value 383. This means that your expression evaluates to true only if the result of calling the dihy() function is 0 or 1, and not 353 and 383.